# Merging rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, node.js

This is the Category model:

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    image:String,
    description:String,
    series: [
      {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: "Series"
      }
     ]
});

module.exports= mongoose.model("Category",categorySchema);
```

And This is the series model

```js
var mongoose=require("mongoose");
//making the schema
var seriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    type:String,
    application:String,
    product:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId ,
        ref:"Product"
    }]
});

module.exports=mongoose.model("Series",seriesSchema);
```

So each Category includes some series that has a name and an application and series in an array.

[My table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKLRB.png) and this is the original code:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thread>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Name</th>
            <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Application</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        <% Category.series.forEach(function(series){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><strong><a href="/categories/<%=Category._id%>/series/<%=series._id%>/products"><%=series.name%></a></strong></td>
            <td><em><%=series.application%></em></td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to merge rows that have the same content. I tried to use a for loop which ended up screwing the whole thing [new results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSeMK.png):

```html
<table class="table">
    <thread>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Name</th>
          <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Application</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        <% for(var i=1;i<series.length;i++){ %>
        <tr>
            <td><strong><a href="/categories/<%=Category._id%>/series/<%=series[i-1]._id%>/products"><%=series[i-1].name%></a></strong></td>
            <% var j=1;%>
            <% console.log(series[i]);%>
            <% if(series[i-1].application==series[i].application){ %>
                <% j++; %>
                <td rowspan="<%=j%>"><em><%=series[i-1].application%></em></td>
            <% } else { %>
              <td><em><%=series[i-1].application%></em></td>
            <% } %>
            <% j=0;%>
        </tr>
        <% }; %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add an MCVE. Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @David Would you please clarify more. I tried to include as much useful information as possible about the problem

Comment: Please show us the structure of `Category.series` and tell us which templating engine you do use. What we can see so far is how you try to render the data and what the outcome is. That's not enough to give you a working solution.

Comment: @David I added the two models. I use mongoose for data modeling

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you really don't have rows with equal content in them. They *either* differ in the first column or in both. Anyway, it appears to me as if you'd try to combine the rows *if their contents are equal in the second column*.

In case it is OK to *loose* the information inside the first column, you'll want to just skip the entire row. Just move the comparison *before you render the `<tr>`*. Don't forget that you have to render the first row in any case. For example:

```html
<table class="table">
    <thread>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Name</th>
          <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Application</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        <% for(var i = 0; i < series.length; i++){ %>
            <% if(i < 1){ %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                        <a href="/categories/<%=Category._id%>/series/<%=series[i]._id%>/products"><%=series[i].name%>
                        </a>
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <em><%=series[i].application%></em>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% } else if(series[i-1].application !== series[i].application){ %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                        <a href="/categories/<%=Category._id%>/series/<%=series[i]._id%>/products"><%=series[i].name%>
                        </a>
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <em><%=series[i].application%></em>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% }; %>
        <% } %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The other possibility would be to combine *the values of the first column*. Solving that inside the loop is going to get fuzzy. It's easier to combine the information *before* you render them, although you have to utilize a bit more extra JavaScript for it. The JS changes the structure in such a way, that it merges contents in the first column together (`link` in the code below) if they have the same application:

```js
function mergeEqApplications (series) {
  return series.reduce(function (acc, s) {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(s.application)) {
      acc[s.application] = {
        link: [{name: s.name, id: s._id}],
        application: s.application
      };
    } else {
      acc[s.application].link.push({name: s.name, id: s._id});
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

function objToArray (obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; });
}

function convert (series) {
  return objToArray(mergeEqApplications(series));
}

Category.series = convert(Category.series);
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thread>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Name</th>
          <th scope="col" class="mytable">Series Application</th>
        </tr>
    </thread>
    <tbody>
        <% Category.series.forEach(function (series) { %>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong>
                    <% series.link.forEach(function (info) { %>
                    <a href="/categories/<%= Category._id %>/series/<%= info.id %>/products">
                      <%= info.name %>
                    </a>
                    <% }); %>
                </strong>
            </td>
            <td>
                <em><%= series.application %></em>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```